# JavaScript : taking result of the first loop and adding it to next one

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out the right logic to do cumulative results in my javascript loop.

Here's what I'm trying to do :

first cumulative value = fixed value -> display

-- loop --

seconde cumulative value = first cumulative value + another value -> display

-- loop --

third cumulative value = second cumulative value + another value -> display

And so on... I hope it's clear enough

Comment: you might want to add some code.. but a solution might be to declare a variable outside of the loop and just use that to store the cumulative value?

Comment: [__`Array#reduce`__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var array = [1,2,3];
var sum = 0; //cumulative value stored outside of loop closure
for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
   sum = sum + array[i];
   console.log(sum);
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's the idea, thank you very much, I figured out now :)

Answer (score 0):

Use parameter outside loop and `+=` to add fixed value to it. `el.innerHTML` for display:

```js
var fixedValue = 5;
var curValue = 0;
var values = document.getElementById('values');

for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  curValue += fixedValue;

  values.innerHTML = values.innerHTML + '<br/>' + curValue;
}
```

```html
<span id="values"></span>
```

Comment: Thank you, helped me figuring out what i wanted :)